# Snap two vertices into midpoint of them

Tags: python, vertices

I have two vertices, A and B ,I want to snap/move(not merge) A and B into midpoint of them 
(snap into M, MA=MB). Is there any way to quickly do it ? ( my object has many vertices that have to do like that).
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select two vertices in *Edit mode* and type
<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Explanation:

(Scale 0)

In the image below the tool tip indicates the median point is used for this user operation.

[image]

The gold planes had the same relative positions as the cyan planes.  The steps written above were applied to place the vertices in the same location.

Comment: i was trying figure out how to do something very similar to this, +1 for **median**